# Whether element is behind inner nested scroll

Tags: javascript, dom, getboundingclientrect

How to detect if an element inside a scrollable block is visible to user (i.e. is in the visible area of the scrollable parent)?

Is there a universal solution, **not involving iterating over all parent nodes** that have scroll?

P.S. One idea I had was `getElementAtPoint`, however it gives me headaches when I need to determine if at least *50%* of the element is visible. So ideally the solution must involve collision detection between two rectangles: the element rectangle and the window.

P.P.S. Another idea I've come up with is to use `scrollIntoView` on the element in question, determine the difference in its position, and then scroll it back to original position. It appears `scrollIntoView` always does the right thing – scrolls both window *and* the inner scrollable blocks!

Comment: What problem you want to solve it?

Comment: @maximkou, I want to check if element is visible on screen (assuming it can only be hidden behind scroll overflow).

Comment: Maybe will this code help you: https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear/blob/master/jquery.appear.js

Comment: Or this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Comment: @maximkou, those only assume window scroll, not inner elements scroll.

Comment: @katspaugh Well, I was just going to remove my comment, since I realized this. Also noticed you've tagged `getBoundingClientRect` too.

Comment: @Teemu, rest assured that your input is appreciated anyway.

Comment: @katspaugh I tried to implement this with a simple iteration at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bZx97/), but it works correctly only in IE9 -10. Looks like other browsers are giving different values from `body/html.getBoundingClientRect()`.

Comment: @Teemu, it represents the idea quite nicely, thank you! If you posted it as an answer I would gladly upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this can't be done without iterating, and even less cross-browser, with some simple code.

Here's an example, how this can be done in IE. Unfortenately other browsers seem to return different values from `body/html.getBoundingClientRect()`. Also margins are treated differently, (IE ignores, others take them account).

```
getVisibilityPercent = function () {
    var target = document.getElementById('target'),
        height = target.offsetHeight,
        parent = target.parentElement,
        targetRect = target.getBoundingClientRect(),
        tLim, bLim,
        percent = 1;
    while (parent) {
        parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
        tLim = Math.max(targetRect.top, parentRect.top); 
        bLim = Math.min(targetRect.bottom, parentRect.bottom);
        percent *= (bLim - tLim) / height;
        percent = (percent < 0) ? 0 : percent;
        parent = parent.parentElement;
    }
    return +((percent * 100).toFixed(2));
};
```